# I cannot type anything in Minecraft PE?

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a Motorola XOOM and it wont let me type on anything. I cannot create signs, enter IP addresses, or name maps at all.

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 3):

Some devices are known to not accept text at all when playing Minecraft Pocket Edition.

There is a workaround in the free Android app [BlockLauncher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.zhuoweizhang.mcpelauncher&hl=en). It is included in both the free version and the Pro version ($1.70).

It allows you to enter text, which is inserted to the game. It is vital for devices that will not feed text directly into Minecraft Pocket Edition.