# Typing into signs crash the game

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-bedrock-edition

This has been an issue since 11.0, or so.

When I place a sign and I start typing, it either closes the game without saving or it shuts down my entire device (kindle fire).

If one happens to work I can only read it when it's on a two blocks space (at eye level) and I have to shift a certain way to see parts of it.

Why is this happening to me and how can I fix it?

Comment: This may help: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/203980/why-cant-i-read-signs-in-minecraft-pe

Comment: Are you placing the sign at the build limit? That instantly crashes the game immediately on older versions of the game, that could be the problem

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use [Block Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.zhuoweizhang.mcpelauncher&hl=en) as a workaround. It's an Android App that allows you to enter text, which is inserted to the game.

According to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/133028/28182), the text mode is used as a workaround for devices that don't allow you to enter text at all into Minecraft Pocket Edition - it should also work for your purposes.